# Covariant representable functors preserve monomorphisms. What about contravariant representable functors?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Category Theory in context and I got a bit confused by problem 2.1.ii. The problem is as follows:

> Prove that if $F: C \rightarrow \text{Set}$ is representable, then $F$ preserves monomorphisms, i.e., sends every monomorphism in $C$ to an injective function. Use the contrapositive to find a covariant set-valued functor defined on your favorite concrete category that is not representable.

I proved the result for covariant functors, and was thinking about how to dualize to get one for contravariant functors. If my understanding is correct, a contravariant representable functor $F: C \rightarrow \text{Set}$ is the same data as a covariant representable functor $F: C^{\text{op}} \rightarrow \text{Set}$, IE, a functor isomorphic to $C^\text{op}(c^\text{op}, -)$.

Then by the result for covariant functors, if a morphism $f: y \rightarrow x$ is an epimorphism then $f^\text{op}: x^\text{op} \rightarrow y^\text{op}$ is a monomorphism, so $Ff$ is a monomorphism. So contravariant functors flip epis to monos. But this is not what we want according to the problem. Is the problem just not specific to contravariant functors or is my logic wrong somehow?

Comment: The problem is probably not specific to contravariant representability, although you do note essentially the right thing: $F\colon C^\text{op} \to \mathrm{Set}$ takes monomorphisms _in $C^\text{op}$_ to injections, so the result still holds for $F$ as a _covariant functor on $C^\text{op}$_, just not for $F$ as a contravariant functor on $C$. One of the dangers of not distinguishing between representable and corepresentable...